# NSBatchUpdateRequest raise an error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

This is my `NSBatchUpdateRequest`:

```
    let batchUpdateRequest = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "WLItem")
    batchUpdateRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "source != rt")
    batchUpdateRequest.propertiesToUpdate = ["position": 2]
    batchUpdateRequest.resultType = NSBatchUpdateRequestResultType.UpdatedObjectsCountResultType

    do {
        let batchUpdateResult = try NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext().executeRequest(batchUpdateRequest) as! NSBatchUpdateResult
    } catch {
        print("error: \(error)")
    }
```

output on console is:

> error: NilError

What is wrong? Is it a problem with XCode7? I  am working with `NSBatchUpdateRequest` first time, so I do not know whether was it like that before or not. For me that code should just works.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I see exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to refresh your managedContextObject to update the database. I have created a function in which am using the NSBatchUpdateRequest to update the database. Below is the function:-

```
 let managedContext = SharedInstance.appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext


func updateDataFromTable(tableName:String, idOfPaticularTable ID:String, updatedDict:Dictionary<String, String>, success:@escaping (_ response:Bool)-> Void, failure:@escaping (_ error: Error?) -> Void) {

    let batchRequest = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: tableName)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", ID)

    batchRequest.predicate = predicate
    batchRequest.propertiesToUpdate = updatedDict

    batchRequest.resultType = .updatedObjectIDsResultType
    do {
        // Execute Batch Request
        let batchUpdateResult = try managedContext?.execute(batchRequest) as! NSBatchUpdateResult

        // Extract Object IDs
        let objectIDs = batchUpdateResult.result as! [NSManagedObjectID]

        for objectID in objectIDs {
            // Turn Managed Objects into Faults
            let managedObject = managedContext?.object(with: objectID)
            managedContext?.refresh(managedObject!, mergeChanges: false)
        }
        success(true)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
        failure(error)
    }
}

struct SharedInstance {

   static let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

   static let employeetable = "EmployeeModel"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem that I faced in my project. Below solution working for me. Try this

```
        let batchRequest = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "Card") 
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "set == %@", set)

        batchRequest.predicate = predicate
        batchRequest.propertiesToUpdate = [ "count" : 54 ] 

        batchRequest.resultType = .UpdatedObjectsCountResultType
        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.executeRequest(batchRequest) as! NSBatchUpdateResult
        } catch _ {
        }
```